# Time to play some

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

What two-word answer is hidden below?

---

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First lets solve the rebuses!

> TABLE TENNIS (table ten is)
>  GOLF (gulf)
>  SQUASH
>  TENNIS (ten is)
>  POOL
>  CRICKET
>  BOWLING (bowl in G)
>  SOCCER (Swedish for sugar is [socker](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/socker#Swedish))

These are all

> ball sports!

As indicated

> by the increasing circle sizes, we sort by [ball size](https://www.topendsports.com/resources/equipment/ball-size.htm) and then extract the specified letter (shifting if indicated by addition)
>  4th+1    SQUA(**B**)SH
>  2nd      T**A**BLE TENNIS
>  3rd      GO**L**F
>  4th      POO**L**
>  6th      TENNI**S**
>  3rd      CR**I**CKET
>  3rd+3    BOW(**Z**)LING
>  5th      SOCC**E**R

And the answer is

> **BALL SIZE**!

Comment: Indeed, well done!